# Moving from "Blank Activity" to "Navigation Drawer Activity"

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

**Statement:**

I am developing an application using Android Studio.
I have Login Page as my main activity and I want that when a user successfully login. He then move to a Navigation Drawer.
For that purpose I have a login button on my login page. And under a login Button i am using the following code:-

```
public void Login_Attempt() {
    Button login_btn;
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_id);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_id);
    login_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);

    login_btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (email.getText().toString().equals("teacher") &&
                            pass.getText().toString().equals("teacher")) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, " Successfully Login ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent teacher = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Teacher.class);
                        startActivity(teacher);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, " Login Failed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                }

            }
    );

}
```

**Problem:**
When I click on button while running my app. After Successful login Application Crashes.

Please help me where am I doing wrong or else please refer me a tutorial where this kind of situation is handled. Any help will be appreciated.

**LogCat Error:**

[image]

---

**Edited:**
Here is what I have found that Teacher Activity is Not Showing any layout.
[image]

If this is what the problem is Kindly let me know how to rectify it.

Comment: Post stacktrace of error and  code of Teacher Activity.

Comment: Teacher activity is a _navigation drawer activity_ and is showing no errors and has no code so far. I just simply added a new _Navigation Drawer Activity_ named **Teacher** .. and under click button i added above code.

Comment: And when your app crash, what are you getting in log? Also have you defined Teacher Activity in AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Error appears in app "Unfortunately ARS has stopped" **Crash**, when i put "teacher" as email and "teacher" as password (which is a successful login criteria). Yes, I have defined Teacher Activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Kindly, refer to my edit in question. If this is the problem then help me out with that.

Comment: When the app crashes, a stacktrace is shown in the LogCat, copy that in the question.

Comment: Do you have the support library included with gradle?

Comment: No i have not.. Kindly tell me how to do that. May be that will solve my problem

Comment: [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

Comment: Yes they are installed.. The problem is somewhere else

Comment: Then logcat message is still required.

Comment: Added a Screenshot for LogCat Errors

Comment: What is line 38 in your teacher class?

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_teacher); is the line 38